# How to center a span over an image in a table cell

Tags: html, css

The goal is to do the following, where the blue recatngles are images with fixed size and 'words' are centered over these images :

[image]

To do this with a **table** it seems that I need to set the **td** and **span** positions to absolute, but then the next cell  ('text cell') overlaps the first one, and trying to set its position to relative has no effect. Setting 'left' has no effect either ...

Here is the solution I have tried:

```
<style>
    #column0 {
        position: absolute;
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align: middle;
        line-height: 50px;
    }
    #column0 span {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
    }
    #column1 {
        position: relative;
    }
</style>

<table>
    <tr><td id="column0"><img .../><span>word</span></td><td id="column1">text cell</td></tr>
</table>
```

How would you do this?
Do I need to forget table?

---

**A solution that works (with fixed size), thanks to the comments below:**

```
</style>
    #column0 {
        display:inline-block;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        background-image: url(...);
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align: middle;
        line-height: 50px;
    }
    #column1 {
        display:inline-block;
    }
</style>
<div>
    <div id="column0">word</div><div id="column1">text cell</div>
</div>
```

Comment: use a div and use the img as the background graphics. Then center the text in the div.

Comment: if you don't need to use tables, use div layouts.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know this way to insert images with background-image, updated my post with a solution

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
#column0 {
    position: relative; /* should keep it in the layout */
}
#column0 span {
    position: absolute; /* should rip it out of the layout */
    top: 15px; /* just a wild guess here */
    left: 15px;
}
```

The key is to set a parent relative and a child absolute. Absolute should rip it out of the layout and position it relative to the nearest positioned parent.

Comment: relative position didn't work with table cell even (but it works with divs). Finally I used divs and it works. Thanks.

Comment: Fascinating, I guess that's why table cells are always a bad idea for laying things out